# Error on python - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string

I'm starting to code right now, but I've searched on google and found an answer: I know the problem is a variable that is already predefined in python that needs to be renamed, but I can't find it. Can someone help me?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

lista_arquivo = os.listdir(fr"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\cursos\projetos\PYTHON\Faturamento_AM")

print(lista_arquivo)

tabela_total = pd.DataFrame()

for arquivo in lista_arquivo:
    
    if "abril.xlsx" in arquivo():
               
        tabela = pd.read_excel(fr"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\cursos\projetos\PYTHON\Faturamento_AM\{arquivo}")
        tabela_total = tabela_total.append(tabela)
        print(arquivo)

        print(tabela_total)

tabela_faturamento = tabela_total.groupby('Faturamento').sum()
print(tabela_faturamento)
```

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I tried renaming the file, putting 'r', 'f' before the directory path, putting {file} at the end of the directory path...

Comment: `if "abril.xlsx" in arquivo():` should be `if "abril.xlsx" in arquivo:`.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in

```
if "abril.xlsx" in arquivo():
```

it should be:

```
if "abril.xlsx" in arquivo:
```

When you are adding `()` to the variable name it is trying to "call" it - execute as a function, but it is string, that's why you're getting error